# Error de traducción de código de java a C#

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, traducción

Bueno verán el problema es que estoy traduciendo un código, de java a C#, que realiza el cifrado de un archivo de texto por el método de *Huffman*. En java el programa original corre perfecto, pero la cuestión aquí es que lo necesito en C#.

Lo estoy tratando de traducir a C#, pero me genera 4 errores dentro del los métodos de `setPrefixCodes` y `buildTree`, los cuales no entiendo nada y no se que es lo estoy traduciendo mal, o si necesito implementar alguna otra cosa.

Realmente necesito saber como traducirlo de manera correcta.

¡Ayuda!

```
namespace Huffman_v2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

        String documento;
        private static IDictionary<char, string> charPrefixHashMap = new Dictionary<char, string>();
        internal static HuffmanNode root;

        private void btnCifrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txtText = documento;
            IDictionary<char, int> freq = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < txtText.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!freq.ContainsKey(txtText[i]))
                {
                    freq[txtText[i]] = 0;
                }
                freq[txtText[i]] = freq[txtText[i]] + 1;
            }
            txtFrecuencia.Text = freq.ToString();
            root = buildTree(freq);
            setPrefixCodes(root, new StringBuilder());
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < txtText.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = txtText[i];
                s.Append(charPrefixHashMap[c]);
            }
            string xs = decode(s.ToString());
            txtPrefijos.Text = charPrefixHashMap.ToString();
            txtCifrado.Text = xs.ToString();
        }

        private static void setPrefixCodes(HuffmanNode node, StringBuilder prefix)
        {
            if (node != null)
            {
                if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
                {
                    charPrefixHashMap[node.data] = prefix.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    prefix.Append('0');
                    setPrefixCodes(node.left, prefix);
                    prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.Length - 1);  //error en .deleteChatAt
                    prefix.Append('1');
                    setPrefixCodes(node.right, prefix);
                    prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.Length - 1);  //error en .deleteChatAt
                }
            }
        }

        private static string decode(string s)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            HuffmanNode temp = root;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                int j = int.Parse(s[i].ToString());
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    temp = temp.left;
                    if (temp.left == null && temp.right == null)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(temp.data);
                        temp = root;
                    }
                }
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    temp = temp.right;
                    if (temp.left == null && temp.right == null)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(temp.data);
                        temp = root;
                    }
                }
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private static HuffmanNode buildTree(IDictionary<char, int> freq)
        {
            PriorityQueue<HuffmanNode> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<HuffmanNode>();  // esta linea tiene el error en PriorityQueue<HuffmanNode> 
            ISet<char> keySet = (ISet<char>)freq.Keys;
            foreach (char? c in keySet)
            {
                HuffmanNode huffmanNode = new HuffmanNode();
                huffmanNode.data = (char)c;
                huffmanNode.frequency = freq.get(c);  //aquí en .get
                huffmanNode.left = null;
                huffmanNode.right = null;
                priorityQueue.offer(huffmanNode);
            }
            Debug.Assert(priorityQueue.size() > 0);
            while (priorityQueue.size() > 1)
            {
                HuffmanNode x = priorityQueue.peek();
                priorityQueue.poll();
                HuffmanNode y = priorityQueue.peek();
                priorityQueue.poll();
                HuffmanNode sum = new HuffmanNode();
                sum.frequency = x.frequency + y.frequency;
                sum.data = '-';
                sum.left = x;
                sum.right = y;
                root = sum;
                priorityQueue.offer(sum);
            }
            return priorityQueue.poll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuáles son los errores que te da?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En C#, a diferencia de Java, se acostumbra poner el nombre de los métodos con la primera letra en mayúscula. El compilador te protesta porque la clase StringBuilder no encuentra un método: `deleteCharAt`.

Sin embargo, ese método (`DeleteCharAt`) no existe en la clase StringBuilder de C#, tendrás que reemplazar esas invocaciones por algo similar a lo siguiente:

`prefix.Remove(prefix.Length - 1, 1);`

Comment: esto es mas un comentariio que una respuesta a la pregunta, deberias de borrarlo

Comment: El autor menciona que está traduciendo un programa de Java a C#. Y de hecho estoy señalando claramente por qué el compilador de C# le está arrojando el error., No entiendo por qué crees que es un comentario. Hasta hay un comentario del autor en el código señalando su problema, a eso es a lo que hago referencia